# Why does my Keyboard update or rebuild my screen, when I click the check button on the keyboard or the keyboard closes?Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am displaying information from the database using future builder and it is displayed in the textformfield, the problem appears when I click the check button on my keyboard.

So the problem is when I try to change the information of the textforfield and I click on the check button on the keyboard, the information that appears from the beginning appears and not the one that I want to edit or update

Example:: Kane appears in the image (this information comes from the database) and you want to edit Kane and write Kane wood and then you click on the check button on the keyboard or close the keyboard. Once you clicked on the button that I mentioned, it reappears as it was at the beginning, in this case Kane and and not Kane Wood.

```
final  Correo =  TextEditingController();
  final NombreUsuario =  TextEditingController();

Widget FullName(nombreusuario){
    return new Container(
        child:  new TextFormField(
          controller: nombreusuario,
          validator:(value){ 
            if(value.isEmpty){
              return "El nombre del usuario no pued quedar vacío";
            }else if(value.length < 1 && value.length > 50){
              return "El correo es muy corto o es muy largo";
            }
            return null;
          },
          decoration:  InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle),
              labelText: 'Nombre de usuario',
              suffixIcon: IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.cancel,color: Colors.black,),
                  onPressed: () {
                    nombreusuario.clear();
                  }
              )
          ),
        ),
    );
  }
   

     @override
          void initState() {
           fup =   editarperfilservices.EditarPerfil() ;
            super.initState();
          }
    
         @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return FutureBuilder(
                        future: fup,
            builder:(context, AsyncSnapshot  snapshot) {
              List  busqueda = snapshot.data;
              if(snapshot.hasData ) {
              return   Center(
                    child: new Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                    child: new ListView.builder(
             itemCount: busqueda.length,
             itemBuilder: (context,i){
              Correo.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioCorreo ;
              NombreUsuario.text = busqueda[i].UsuarioApodo ;
              return Container(
                  child: ListView(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                      children:[
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        FullName(NombreUsuario),
                        SizedBox(height: 18,),
                        CorreoF2(Correo), ]
                  ),);
            }  ) ));
            }else if(snapshot.hasError){
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            } return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVCG8.png)

Comment: You lost me there with the "check button on the keyboard". I am not familiar with that key.

Comment: updated, there is the image